# Benefits of creating an custom ActionBar over just creating the layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been trying to implement a custom action bar but I keep getting a null pointer exception because of the below code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.home_action_bar);
}
```

Apparently, `getSupportActionBar` returns null. After trying to make it work for a couple of hours with no luck, I start to think to myself why I really need to make it a custom action bar. I was able to create the design I want and it looks just fine as shown in the image below, without the above code, or without trying to create a custom action bar, the white region is a scrollView, and the contents will go behind the action bar. So my question now is, it it necessary to make the custom action bar work, and it is, why won't the above code work?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `getSupportActionBar` returning null?

You are probably using a `NoActionBar` theme like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`,

Remove the `NoActionBar` part.

Like `Theme.AppCompat.Light` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

> Why use ActionBar instead of layout?

**Reason 1**

Creating custom layout will add a lot of boilerplate code. `Actionbar` is usually kept consistent among all the activities of your app. So if you use a layout, then you will end up adding the same layout code to all your activity layouts. ( Even if you are including the layout using the `<layout/>` tag, it's still unnecessary code).

**Reason 2**

You will have `action items` in your `ActionBar`. Using a custom layout, you would end up calling `findViewById` on these `action items` in each of your activity. `findViewById` is a costly operation. So it will definitely effect your app's performance (maybe very negligible but still). Also, this is unecessary code you need to write in each activity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The problem with removing NoActionBbar is that there are pages in which I do not want to support ActionBar, and there are others that require it, how do I specify that ?

Comment: In your manifest, set `NoActionBar` for the `application`. This will set `NoActionBar` for all the activities. But for the activities where you don't want the actionbar, set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: I have done exactly that, it does not work, it still throws the null pointer exception

Comment: have you tried `getSupportActionBar().hide();` ? Don't use `NoActionBar` in any of your themes. Instead, in the activity where you want to hide the support action bar, use`getSupportActionBar().hide();`